# Unable to Reload QlikView Report from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: qlikview, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to ask for advise on why I am unable to load QlikView Report from Task Scheduler if I select "Run whether user is logged on or not" in General Tab in Windows Task Scheduler. However, when I select "Run only when user is logged on", then QlikView Report are able to be reloaded successfully.

**Unable to Load QlikView Report**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp1Ak.png

**Able to Load QlikView Report**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnori.png

I have also tried to update the other settings in Windows Task Scheduler.